# ARM assembly question wiht hexidecimal values

Tags: math, assembly, arm, hex

If i have 0x00000065 stored in a register, is that the same as having 0X65 in my register?

Thank you so much.

Comment: yes. The leading zeros contribute nothing to the real value

Comment: It's the same with the denary numbers you're used to, if you have $2 or $0000002 you have the same amount of money.

Comment: what does this have to do with assembly, and if it is an assembly question show the assembly and indicate which assembler you are using as the assembler determines how numbers are interpreted/used not the target instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same two hexadecimal values:

0x00000065 = 5*(16^0) + 6*(16^1) + 0*(16^2) + ... + 0*(16^7) = 5*(16^0) + 6*(16^1) = 0x65

(Note: the symbol '^' denotes the power operator)